# Android Capture All Audio Going to Speakers

Tags: android

In Android, is there a way to capture all of the audio going to the speakers(or headphones) and save it, to a file for example?  For the app I am making, it would be a nice feature if I could pipe all of the sound somewhere else.  I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055272/android-4-0-ideas-how-to-record-capture-internal-audio-e-g-stream-music) but I wouldn't want to have to have users to have a custom ROM to use the feature.  Root access won't be a problem.  Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that without providing a custom operating system. Root access wouldn't help, since the suitable API call to [AudioFlinger](http://www.slideshare.net/fefe7270/android-audio-systemaudioflinger) does not exist.

Comment: Is there a list of custom ROMs that support this? Also, is it possible to install or develop a kernel driver to do it? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: A kernel driver alone probably wouldn't help much. I actually implemented this functionality as an experiment at my former workplace, on a device based on Qualcomm's APQ8064 platform. If I remember correctly (I no longer have access to that code), I had to make changes in the kernel/msm, hardware/qcom/audio, system/core and frameworks/base gits.

Comment: @Michael Interesting, thanks for the info.